# How can I drop the "belongs to integers" part from Reduce output?

Tags: expression-manipulation, rule

I have this *Mathematica* line:

```
Reduce[1/(E^0)^x + 1/(E^1)^x + 1/(E^3)^x == 0, x]
```

that gives the output:

> ```
> C[1] ∈ 
>   Integers && (x == 
>     I π + 2 I π C[1] + Log[-Root[1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]] || 
>    x == 2 I π C[1] + Log[Root[1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]] || 
>    x == 2 I π C[1] + Log[Root[1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]])
> ```

when copy pasted into the question box at *Mathematica Stackexchange*.

I would like to drop the part:

```
C[1] ∈ 
  Integers &&
```

from the beginning of the output above so that I can apply the `ToRules` command like this:

```
{ToRules[(x == 
     I π + 2 I π C[1] + Log[-Root[1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]] || 
    x == 2 I π C[1] + Log[Root[1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]] || 
    x == 2 I π C[1] + Log[Root[1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]])]}
```

How can I get rid of the `C[1]∈Integers &&` in the output above from the program involving `Reduce`?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: What is `log3`?

Comment: log3 is just a variable. Could have been "y" also.

Comment: Now I see, I forgot to define log3.

Comment: I changed the log3 variable into the value 3, a constant. It should be fine now.

Comment: Why not `List[ToRules@(Reduce[1/(E^0)^x + 1/(E^1)^x + 1/(E^3)^x == 0, x] /. C[1] -> 0)]`?

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @MatsGranvik I'm speculating here, but my guess is that the downvote was for one of the first versions of the question, which had a number of formatting problems.

Comment: Yes I had some difficult to read code in the first version.

Comment: In this particular problem, the output from `Reduce` has head `And` and since `Last` works with any head if you do, say, `sol = Reduce[1/(E^0)^x + 1/(E^1)^x + 1/(E^3)^x == 0, x]];`, then `Last@sol` will give you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Simplify.html) with assumptions:

```
Simplify[
 Reduce[1/(E^0)^x + 1/(E^1)^x + 1/(E^3)^x == 0, x],
 C[1] ∈ Integers]
(*
  x == I π (1 + 2 C[1]) + Log[-Root[1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]] || 
   x == 2 I π C[1] + Log[Root[1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]] || 
   x == 2 I π C[1] + Log[Root[1 + #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]]
*)
```

That way I'm fairly confident the transformations are mathematically sound (as long as I keep to the assumptions).